# openlayers 3 : Create custom library

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I'm currently using openlayers 3.4.0. I want to add SetZIndex and GetZIndex methods to OL 3.4.0 (from latest version 3.14.1). Could you please someone tell me, How to create custom library or separate file without altering the ol.js file?

Answer (score 1):

Fork it, pull in the change, and build it. More info at: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md

Comment: I don't want to add custom code to ol.js and rebuild. Custom code should be in separate file. I tried to override the function in Maprenderer.js file but it is not working :-(